# Fat arrow function's scope and jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

Compare the following syntax:

```
$(elem).on('mouseenter', () => { console.log(this); })
```

In this case, `this` refers to `this` in parent's scope, where as in

```
$(elem).on('mouseenter', function() { console.log(this); })
```

`this` refers to the DOM's element. I found [this article](http://jsrocks.org/2014/10/arrow-functions-and-their-scope/) which basically says this is an expected feature. I wonder why? Is it because technically `=>` is not a function and therefore doesn't introduce a new scope? Could someone point me to the place in the spec of the language that talks about this?

Thanks

Comment: Essentially, `() => {}` is the same as `function() {}.bind(this)`

Comment: all function literals have outside reach defined at creation time, called closure. fat arrows also have `this` defined at creation time, rather than the traditional call-time.

Comment: @dandavis that's best 2-liner I have ever read. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone point me to the place in the spec of the language that talks about this?

The specification [is here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

See:

> 2. Let scope be the LexicalEnvironment of the running execution context.

And:

> An ArrowFunction does not define local bindings for arguments, super, this, or new.target. Any reference to arguments, super, this, or new.target within an ArrowFunction must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing environment. Typically this will be the Function Environment of an immediately enclosing function.